# How to find a string before an other string in php

Tags: php, string

I am trying to find and change a string found before an other string.

```
<div class="item" ....>
<img scr="rambo" />
```

This code repeats for every movie. I have to set the item class for any chosen movie to

```
<div class="item active" ....>
<img scr="rambo" />
```

So I am looking for the first class before any given movietitle and then set it to active.

(In the code, where i placed the dots, there is a lot of code that keeps changing (like coordinates) so I can't count backwards to that position.)

Can someone help me with this? Thnx.

This is the actual code for 2 movies wich is created by a javascript coverflow script:

```
<div class="item " href="cover.php?film=Terminator 2" style="display: block; left: 452.383126009628px; top: 176.25px; height: 264.375px; width: 117.666903409091px; font-size: 50%; z-index: 32765; visibility: visible;">
<canvas class="content portray" src="films/Terminator 2/cover.jpg" origproportion="0.6676136363636364" width="235" height="528"></canvas>
<div class="caption">Terminator 2 Judgment Day
<div class="cover_beschrijving">
<div class="cover_left">
<ul>
<li><h1>jaar:</h1>1991</li>
<li><h1>genre:</h1>Actie</li>
<li><h1>speelduur:</h1>137 minuten</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
<div class="cover_right">--Movie discription--</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="item  active" href="cover.php?film=The Fast and the Furious" style="display: block; left: 727.832386363636px; top: 0px; height: 528.75px; width: 236.335227272727px; font-size: 100%; z-index: 32768; visibility: visible;">
<canvas class="content portray" src="films/The Fast and the Furious/cover.jpg" origproportion="0.6704545454545454" width="236" height="528"></canvas>
<div class="caption">The Fast and the Furious
<div class="cover_beschrijving">
<div class="cover_left">
<ul>
<li><h1>jaar:</h1>2001</li>
<li><h1>genre:</h1>Actie</li>
<li><h1>speelduur:</h1>107 minuten</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
<div class="cover_right">---Movie discription---</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Can you post the actual code that is giving you trouble? Also, are you generating this HTML, or is it coming from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **preg_replace** to find the strings and replace them. This regex `<div\sclass=\"item\".*>` will match `<div class="item" ....>` If you want to include the img tag in the match, you have to modify the regex accordingly, but I don't see why you care for that, if it was me I would stop at `<div class="item"`
Then it's just a matter of providing the replacement string.